# Spin correlations of identical leptons in a Z-boson decay

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, quantum-spin

In 2012, the CMS experiment observed a decay of the $Z$ boson into four leptons: https://inspirehep.net/literature/1190671

The Feynman diagram for this process is shown in this Figure:

[image: Z boson decay to four leptons]

Its final state contains two positive and two negative leptons. Let's consider the case when all leptons have identical flavour (say, are electrons and positrons). It is known that two electrons, being fermions, cannot occupy the same quantum state.

**Question 1:** Does this mean that in the $Z \to e^+e^-e^+e^-$ decay, the first $e^+$ and the second $e^+$ always have opposite spin projections?

To rephrase this quesiton, let's consider a higher-order diagram with an additional emission of a virtual photon leading to yet another electron-positron pair.
This creates a final state with three positrons, which (if the answer to Q1 is positive) must be forbidden as the electron spin can only have two projections.

**Question 2:** Is the decay $Z \to e^+e^-e^+e^-e^+e^-$ forbidden by Fermi-Dirac statistics?

Comment: Spin is one of the possible quantum numbers that will differentiate the  eigenstates of the leptons. In the decay the energy states are continuously available , so there is no problem. It is not a bound state.